# Change settings for diff changes between different Git commits in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, the built-in Git extension indicates diff changes between the current working directory and the LAST commit. It's a blue bar near the line-number bar (as in the picture).[image]

My question: How I can configure so that the Git extension indicates diff changes between the current working directory and ANY PREVIOUS commit (not only the LAST commit).

I've searched but found no result to my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: with gitlens you can add codelens on each line or a blame column

Comment: An alternative is to set up a difftool with VS Code. `git config diff.tool foo; git config difftool.foo.cmd 'code -w -n --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE`. Run `git difftool $commit` to compare the current working tree and the specified commit.

Comment: Thanks you for both great answers. I actually knew these settings, but I want to focus on the vertical bar (as shown in the image attached with the post question). I'm currently working on a maintenance project where I have to modify code on existing lengthy code files. So the vertical bar is what I really want to take advantage for quick indication.